# Linux: command to open URL in default browser

Tags: linux, browser, default

What command we have to execute (from Java, but that should not matter) on Linux (different common distributions) to open a given URL in the default browser?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The most cross-distribution one is `xdg-open http://stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Unfortunately not present in RHEL

Comment: @OndraŽižka sensible-browser is debian-only too, isn't it? What would work in RHEL?

Comment: It exists in RHEL, install the package 'xdg-utils'.

Comment: Not present in my Debian 7. Have to use 'wget' instead.

Comment: In Debian, it's package "xdg-utlls" too, just like in RHEL.

Comment: Why does it always prompt `ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(120) | Failed to launch GPU process.`

Answer (score 50):

I believe the simplest method would be to use Python:

```
python -m webbrowser "http://www.example.com/"
```

Comment: works like a charm. also cross platform (at least works on mac & linux)

Comment: Also on windows if Python is installed.

Comment: I like this solution better for a cross-platform use case, but for Linux only, it does take ~7-8x as much time to run on my system compared to `xdg-open` for the same url.

Comment: Just as a note for people running this on windows: I've found it often opens up Internet Explorer. (instead of the user's configured default) But it works, I guess. 

Comment: What if there are multiple browser profiles?

Answer (score 12):

on ubuntu you can try gnome-open.

$ gnome-open http://www.google.com

Answer (score 8):

In Java (version 6+), you can also do:

```
Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
d.browse(uri);
```

Though this won't work on all Linuxes. At the time of writing, Gnome is supported, KDE isn't.

Answer (score 7):

At least on Debian and all its derivatives, there is a 'sensible-browser' shell script which choose the browser best suited for the given url.

http://man.he.net/man1/sensible-browser

Answer (score 6):

On distributions that come with the open command,

```
$ open http://www.google.com
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 it doesn't work because it tries to open file.

Answer (score 5):

```
###1     Desktop's -or- Console use:
sensible-browser $URL; # Opinion: best. Target preferred APP.
# My-Server translates to: w3m [options] [URL or filename] 
## [ -z "$BROWSER" ] && echo "Empty"
# Then, Set the BROWSER environment variable to your desired browser.

###2     Alternative 
# Desktop (if [command-not-found] out-Dated)
x-www-browser http://tv.jimmylandstudios.xyz # firefox

###3     !- A Must Know -!
# Desktop (/usr/share/applications/*.desktop)
xdg-open $URI # opens about anything on Linux (w/ .desktop file)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some detail to your answer.

Comment: When using any of these commands in a Shell Script you'll need to test if they exist first (e.g. command -v $CMD ). $? = 0

Answer (score 4):

I think using `xdg-open http://example.com` is probably the best choice.

In case they don't have it installed I suppose they might have just `kde-open` or `gnome-open` (both of which take a single file/url) or some other workaround such as looping over common browser executable names until you find one which can be executed(using which). If you want a full list of workarounds/fallbacks I suggest reading xdg-open(it's a shell script which calls out to kde-open/gnome-open/etc. or some other fallback).

But since xdg-open and xdg-mime(used for one of the fallbacks,) are shell scripts I'd recommend including them in your application and if calling `which xdg-open` fails add them to temporary PATH variable in your subprograms environment and call out to them. If xdg-open fails, I'd recommend throwing an Exception with an error message from what it output on stderr and catching the exception and printing/displaying the error message.

I would ignore the java awt Desktop solution as the bug seems to indicate they don't plan on supporting non-gnome desktops anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

I think a combination of xdg-open as described by shellholic and - if it fails - the solution to finding a browser using the `which` command as described [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/open-browser-in-java-windows-or-linux/) is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

For opening a URL in the browser through the terminal, CentOS 7 users can use gio open command. For example, if you want to open google.com then `gio open https://www.google.com` will open google.com URL in the browser.

`xdg-open https://www.google.com` will also work but this tool has been deprecated, Use `gio open` instead. I prefer this as this is the easiest way to open a URL using a command from the terminal.

Answer (score -2):

If you are in Windows10 (including WSL2 *nix shells) you can try:

```
  explorer.exe   https://stackoverflow.com

  or

  cmd.exe /c start   https://stackoverflow.com/?foo=bar
```

Weird but it works!

Note: In the case of WSL there is a known bug which prohibits passing query parameters into the url. The workaround is to use "cmd.exe /c start url"

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3832