# Opening URL within ios application

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I need to open a webpage with safari in my iOS application.
With XE2 there was *iphoneall* unit, which exposed [UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication). XE4 doesn't use FPC anymore, so I can't use that.
[Embarcadero documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Mac_OS_X_Application_Development#Mac_C_Frameworks_.28for_C.2FC.2B.2B_Development.29) 
says I can use SDKs only with C++ or using delphi interfaces (and still, macapi is for OSX only, not iOS). So, it seems that there is no interface for UIKit framework?!
Another solution I tried was:

```
_system('open http://www.google.com');
```

But that had no affect at all!
Is there any other ways to open urls or am I out of luck to accomplish it?
I know there is TWebBrowser component for ios, but I wouldn't want to take that road just to display a webpage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By chance, someone at Embarcadero [posted a code snippet to do exactly this](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/ao/2013/05/01/39454/) two days ago.

If you are using XE4, look in the Samples, and you can find one (sorry, not sure of the name) where the final code is:

```
OpenURL('http://www.embarcadero.com');
```

This uses the XE4 FireMonkey framework and a class helper written by David Clegg, available in the sample.

If you are using an older version of FireMonkey, you can use the rather more cumbersome code:

```
function SharedApplication: UIApplication;
begin
  Result := TUIApplication.Wrap(TUIApplication.OCClass.sharedApplication);
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SharedApplication.openURL(TNSURL.Wrap(TNSURL.OCClass.URLWithString(NSSTR(PChar(String('http://www.embarcadero.com'))))));
end;
```

(Attribution: Code snippets all copied from the [linked blog post](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/ao/2013/05/01/39454/).)

There is also a [very old forum post](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=61584) from the early days of FireMonkey showing how to tackle these problems in general (basically, string <-> NSString <-> NSURL), and while it's a bit out of date - as you can see by the above code, FireMonkey has matured greatly - it may give some insight into the underlying reason for the code.

Comment: thanks, i finally found the Apple.Utils file. It is located in Samples\Delphi\RTL\CrossPlatform Utils folder!