# How to get TLinkLabel Functionality in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

We have URL label [TLinkLabel](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TLinkLabel) component in **VCL**. It seems **FireMonkey** don't have this counterpart. How can we achieve same functionality through code in FireMonkey. That is:

1. Display Underlined Text (Already available)
2. Open Link in Default Browser upon clicking (Needed Functionality)

Any help or pointer is appreciated.

Comment: This question has answers that will solve your probelm of opening link in default browser with FMX: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443264/how-to-open-an-url-with-the-default-browser-with-firemonkey-cross-platform-appli Probably Patrick Premartin answer is what you really need.

Comment: @fpiette Wow. Yes This[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45835401/14807722) solution seems to solve my problem. Thank you so much.