# Launching Web Browser from Linux Terminal (using ssh)

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, browser

I have ssh'd into my raspberry pi which uses Raspian OS (like Debian).  I am trying to launch the default web browser from the terminal but I'm running into problems.  I have looked at this post on [launching web browsers from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116473/linux-command-to-open-url-in-default-browser/9293402#9293402).  I have tried the `xdg-open` and the `sensible-browser` commands however they seem to just display the desired webpage's contents within the terminal.  So no actual web browser is launching in the raspberry pi (which is what I want).  My default web browser is Midori.  So am I using these terminal commands incorrectly, or am I misunderstanding what they are meant to do?  To be clear, I want to actually launch the web browser in the dekstop environment using a terminal command.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

graphic applications need an environment variable called `$DISPLAY` to start.

Start your browser in the terminal via ssh like this for exmaple:

```
user@host:~# DISPLAY=:0 firefox http://www.google.com
```

The browser will be started in the gui. In your case:

```
user@host:~# DISPLAY=:0 midori http://www.google.com
```

Comment: ah that's what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Now I have to figure out how to make the browser full screen from the terminal. I will do some searching

Answer (score 1):

On some raspbian (jessie with PIXEL)
for this to work, we must add the user to the video group to avoid the "failed to open vchiq..." message with :

> usermod -a -G video username

and to avoid the console to hang, open midori with "&" at the end :

> DISPLAY=:0 midori http://www.google.com &

They must be other cleanest methods, but to complete this post, this one fits, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429632/6153083

chromium, for instance, has a kiosk mode. You can start it in kiosk mode using the following switches:

```
chromium-browser --display=:0 --kiosk http://www.google.com
```