# Launching a web browser from command-line Dart script

Tags: dart

I'd like to open a given URL from a small command-line app I wrote in Dart. Any simple way to do it?
This would be similar to Desktop#browse(URI) in Java.

Comment: What OS is the app supposed to run on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code:

```dart
import "dart:io";

void runBrowser(String url) {
  var fail = false;
  switch (Platform.operatingSystem) {
    case "linux":
      Process.run("x-www-browser", [url]);
      break;
    case "macos":
      Process.run("open", [url]);
      break;
    case "windows":
      Process.run("explorer", [url]);
      break;
    default:
      fail = true;
      break;
  }

  if (!fail) {
    print("Start browsing...");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Based on @günter-zöchbauer reply, using xdg-open is the way to go for Linux.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do launch it using `Process.run()` or `Process.start()` and you have to take care of OS differences yourself.

On
- Linux you can use [Linux: command to open URL in default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116473/linux-command-to-open-url-in-default-browser) (needs to be installed but it usually is by default)
- Windows https://superuser.com/questions/36728/can-i-launch-urls-from-command-line-in-windows
- OSX http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/18/open-url-default-web-browser-command-line/

Answer (score 2):

The invoke the **default** browser on Windows:

```
Process.run("start", [url], runInShell: true);
```

(Tested on Windows 7 only though I'm afraid)